# Is it wrong to git push force branches?

Tags: git

When I'm working on a feature branch, I tend to want to [cleanup the commits in the branch using an interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/) before my work is reviewed and integrated in the main branch.

During development of the feature, I want to push my intermediate work to the remote repository as a backup measure. I.e. when my hard-drive crashes, I don't want my entire feature branch to be lost.

However, this leads to the fact that I often have to do a `git push --force` to the remote repository after a rebase, an action which is generally frowned upon. Or as the linked github page says:

> Because changing your commit history can make things
> difficult for everyone else using the repository, it's considered bad
> practice to rebase commits when you've already pushed to a repository.

Is there a (generally accepted) policy that solves this conflict?

#### Why this is not a duplicate of [Is the git "Golden Rule of Rebasing" so essential?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287037/is-the-git-golden-rule-of-rebasing-so-essential)

My question here asks for a policy to solve the conflict between wanting to *backup your work in the remote repository* and *rebasing your work*, while the other question tries to deny that there is a conflict and asks why some people think the conflict exists at all, and thus asks why "it is essential" not to push force rebases?

Comment: You could back up your repository the old-fashioned way every night. Git being distributed has the nice side effect of doubling as a backup but you shouldn't be pushing unfinished work to public repositories as a backup measure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the git "Golden Rule of Rebasing" so essential?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/287037/is-the-git-golden-rule-of-rebasing-so-essential)

Comment: The problem is rebasing. Push normally and do not worry about history, SCMs are supposed to preserve history - its their entire purpose. When merging, use merge instead of rebase. The close-duplicate link shows why.

Comment: @gbjbaanb if you make WIP commits, a rebase is very useful to avoid having many commits for a single days worth of work. I often make commits for small changes just so I have a "undo to a state I remember" option if needed - most of these are irrelevant/noise to the main history of the repo (which is why rebase is so useful).

Comment: @gbjbaanb That's a matter of opinion I think. Many teams use a rebasing strategy to keep their history clean.

Comment: @enderland everyone wants pretty history, its still the wrong (and dangerous) thing to do as shown by the link. Torvalds should never have put it in, he should have allowed commits to be "compressed" on display instead.

Comment: @gbjbaanb but... he didn't, and so we have to work with what we have. To me it is far more useful to have a single commit on the master branch instead of 30+ individual and incremental commits from each feature branch. But everyone will have a different workflow, I guess...

Comment: i wonder why people don't use git flow ...  the flow starts and finishes features, you never push feature branch, or any other kind like hotfix, bugfix etc ...  remote branches must be 2 dev and master

Comment: Never pushing a feature branch is a terrible idea. Do you not ever review other people's code? Or have 100% confidence that your machine will never fail/get stolen or lost? Do you never hand off feature branches? Or use branches as POC or to explore ideas that will never go into main?

Answer (score 7):

The key question to ask yourself:

- Do you keep your remote branch after merging back into master?

If you delete your remote feature branch after merging into master, you already are losing the history. Assuming you squash/rebase the branch prior to making your merge/PR you lose this history. All your force push is doing in this case is allowing you to use github as a backup.

The situation where you would want to keep the history and not force push is if your remote branch is *persisting* after being merged and not only existing for a temporary period of time.

> I suppose you're asking if I would keep the unrebased branch? No, AFAIC. Still, push forcing it might theoretically result in loss of commits from other users who pushed to the same branch

It sounds like you have multiple people pushing to that branch simultaneously. This means you *do* care about the history on the branch.

What you could do instead for your intermediate work is create a fork of that branch. You can push to this and then rebase all your commits into a single commit prior to merging, so when you merge them into your feature-branch, you only have 1 commit (with the rebased history of your entire branch).

Comment: "Do you keep your remote branch after merging back into master?" I suppose you're asking if I would keep the unrebased branch? No, AFAIC. Still, push forcing it might theoretically result in loss of commits from other users who pushed to the same branch.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke I edited a bit about that. FYI

Comment: I think that forking as a measure to prevent destroying commits when push forcing is actually a very good suggestion. But AFAIK it is not really a git concept, and you need a service wrapper around that to do this easily (such as github). Am I correct about that? Or maybe I mistake your use of the term "forking" for just creating a seperate branch?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke well you can accomplish the same thing in a variety of ways. If your feature branch is on the remote repository, you can fork the repo and have your version of that branch. And then merge that branch into your remote branch after squashing commits. Or you can just create a different local branch (maybe `featurebranch-local`) and then do active dev on that branch, with as many commits as you want. Once you want to merge, squash those commits and then merge them into the feature. Basically just doing dev in an actual temporary branch and then squashing/merging into your feature.

Comment: Assuming that forking a repo is out of option because one doesn't use github, we would work with a "private" `develop-feature` branch. Of course the privateness is purely by convention and not enforced by anything, but can be made part of a policy, especially if certain branch naming conventions are introduced for this. (Maybe I'm being too anxious right now, maybe not :) The combination with `--force-with-lease` can't hurt, though shouldn't be relied upon, as pointed out in my other post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm listing some possibilities here that cross my mind.

## Always rebase on a new branch

When having a messy branch `some-feature`, rebase it on a new branch. E.g.

```
$ git checkout -b some-feature-rebase
$ git rebase -i master # etc..
```

Then have `some-feature-rebase` reviewed and integrated.

**Problem:** A big downside here is that, strictly speaking, you need a new branch for every rebase. (You could have multiple rebases if you make changes after a code review, for instance)

## Use `git push --force-with-lease`

I just learned about the [`git push --force-with-lease` alternative to `git push --force`](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/), which

> refuses to update a branch unless it is the state that we expect; i.e. nobody has updated the branch upstream.

**Problem**: This seems to improve directly upon the situation where we use just `--force`, but still has some caveats, most notably when I do a `git fetch` instead of a `git pull`, which updates our local upstream branches, tricking `--force-with-lease` into thinking that no unmerged changes were made on the remote branch.

Comment: This is a lot of ceremony and hand wringing for basically no payoff. How does this work if you have an open PR that has revision requests from your team? Do you nuke the whole PR with it's comments and discussion just to keep some abstract religious idea of "clean" history? Seems absurd.

Comment: @Askdesigners In which sense the PR should be nuked? Ie. Github has no problems. I also do not see it "abstract religious" to reduce noise. You don't want to have noise in source code, in the logs, in the UI (too many notifications) etc. Why would you want it in the git histoy?